# How 'Period' in Cloud Watch Alarm really works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I'm building a cloud watch alarm to send an email when a lambda function is not called in a period of 5 minutes

```yaml
    CloudWatchAlarm:
     Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
     Properties:
      AlarmActions:
        - !Ref SNSTopic
      AlarmDescription: Send email if lambda function was not called within 5 minutes
      Dimensions:
        -
          Name: "FunctionName"
          Value: "my-lambda"
      ComparisonOperator:  LessThanThreshold
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      MetricName: Invocations
      Namespace: AWS/Lambda
      Period: 300
      Statistic: Sum
      Threshold: 1
      TreatMissingData: breaching
      DatapointsToAlarm: 1
```

So, when the function is called, invocation metric goes to one and the alarm enter in OK state. But, when 5 minutes is passed without call the function, the alarm does not come back to ALARM state. Actually it takes like 15 minutes to go to ALARM state.

If I put a minor period, it does take less time to come back to ALARM state. I don't understand how period really works.

Does anybody know if this kind of configuration is really possible in Cloud Watch Alarm? How should I determine period and evaluation period to get the email in exactly 5 minutes ?

Comment: Have you checked if your data is non-breaching? This can prevent the alarm from going into an ALARM state.

Comment: @TeodoricoLevoff 

Yes, actually there will be no datapoints and missing datapoint will be breaching. But this is not happening at the time I expect. Here an example:

1 - I invoke my function at 10:00
2 -  The alarm goes into OK state because there is 1 datapoint with sum > 1 within 5 minutes
3 - I don't call my function anymore
4 - There will be no more data points (missing data is breaching)
5 - The alarm goes to ALARM state after 15 minutes instead of 5 minutes

And I don't understand why it takes more time than the period to change the state

Answer (score 8):

This probably happens because alarm state is not evaluated using `Period`, but so called [evaluation range](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html) which can be much longer the the period. What's more you do not control the evaluation range.

Similar issues of CW delays were discussed in, for example:

- [Unexplainable delay between Alarm data breach and Alarm state change](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=936202)

From the link:

> In this case, for the time when alarm did not transition to OK state, it was using the **previous data points in the evaluation range** to evaluate its state, as expected.

So it seems that in your case the evaluation range reaches 15 minutes back.